# PyTorch v1.12 release with support for GPU-accelerated PyTorch on Macs

Tags: pytorch, metal, torch

Introducing Accelerated PyTorch Training on Mac

https://pytorch.org/blog/introducing-accelerated-pytorch-training-on-mac

Does anyone know whether the PyTorch v1.12 release will support AMD GPUs with Metal?
Does it have to be built from source?

Comment: Right.  So, is the Apple Metal support in the nightly build source?

Comment: @amadan AMD GPUs don't support CUDA.

Comment: PyTorch announced support for Apple Metal in v1.12.  Metal is not CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.
Long answer:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/77867